# JavaFX Ambiguous column name error in simple query

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

Ambiguous column name error is Simple query :

```
 String SQL = "SELECT divisions.division_id, divisions.volume_id, divisions.division_head_count, divisions.division_heading, divisions.messages_bounds FROM divisions";
            ResultSet resultSet = null;
            try {
                resultSet = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);
            } catch (SQLException throwables) {
                throwables.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (resultSet != null) {

                int count = 1;

                while (true) {
                    try {
                        if (!resultSet.next()) break;
                    } catch (SQLException throwables) {
                        throwables.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    try {
                        int division_id = resultSet.getInt("division_id");
                        int volume_id = resultSet.getInt("volume_id");
                        String division_heading = resultSet.getString("division_heading");
                        int division_head_count = resultSet.getInt("division_head_count");
                        String messages = resultSet.getString("messages_bounds");

                        division_id_list.add("" + division_id);
                        volume_id_list.add("" + volume_id);
                        division_heading_list.add(division_head_count + ") " + division_heading+" - ("+ messages+")");
                        totalHadis_list.add(messages);


                    } catch (SQLException throwables) {
                        throwables.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

And the following Error occurred :

```
java.sql.SQLException: ambiguous column: 'division_id'
    at org.sqlite.RS.findColumn(RS.java:108)
    at org.sqlite.RS.getInt(RS.java:228)
    at sample.HadisReading.showHadisDivision(HadisReading.java:282)
    at sample.HadisReading$3.handle(HadisReading.java:200)
    at sample.HadisReading$3.handle(HadisReading.java:190)
```

I have searched and google everywhere but no solutions found fruitful. I have come to know that this problem occurs for being same column name in multiple table. But, I have tried many answer, but no luck. Those answer described about table join or something else that not fit my situation. In my case this is a simple query.

One side note : I have multiple table in the same column name : "division_id" .

How can I get rid from the problem ? any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

At last I found the workaround. As this exception coming from the same column name in multiple table, so, I do the trick is that, to get the string from the column, I have used column index besides column label :

I have used :

```
int division_id = resultSet.getInt(1);
```

instead of :

```
int division_id = resultSet.getInt("division_id");
```

And the error gone, Alhamdulillah.

Comment: The query that you posted in your question is not possible to throw that error because only 1 table is involved (unless `divisions` is a View that selects from multiple tables). Post your actual code.

Comment: @forpas the database has multiple tables, and there is same column name on that tables.

Comment: The error "Ambiguous column name" is thrown in queries that involve multiple joined tables which contain not properly aliased columns with the same name. In a query that involves only 1 table this error is not possible. Post the actual code that throws the error.

Comment: @forpas this is the point. I posted the actual full code, but my query involves only one table. But the exception occurred in JavaFX (with maven) in IntelliJ. why ?  Any Idea ?